Fish script works as function, but not as standalone script
I have a small function that activates my desired Python venv - pya venv python_version - so something like this:
pya vm_info 3.10.12

As a fish function, this works perfectly:
function pya
  set -l venv "$HOME/.local/share/virtualenvs"
  set -l name $argv[1]
  set -l ver $argv[2]

  if not string length -q -- "$ver"
    source $venv/$name/bin/activate.fish
  else
    source $venv/$name-$ver/bin/activate.fish
  end

end

But as a standalone script, it does nothing:
#!/usr/bin/env fish
set -l venv "$HOME/.local/share/virtualenvs"
set -l name $argv[1]
set -l ver $argv[2]

if not string length -q -- "$ver"
  source $venv/$name/bin/activate.fish
else
  source $venv/$name-$ver/bin/activate.fish
end

I've tested to see if the script actually reaches the source statements, and it does. But for some reason, they are silently failing. I have plenty of other fish scripts that run as expected, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

What do you mean by "silently failing"? If you mean that the parent shell does not inherit the virtual environment after the script has run, that's expected AFAIK

Namely, a script is executed in a subprocess, while a function is run in the current shell; the former will only affect the subprocess' environment, while the latter will affect the envrionment of the current shell. In other words, modifications to the environmnent done by a script won't propagate to the parent shell. To fix this, you want to run source script.sh instead of ./script.sh, which will evaluate script.sh in the context of the current shell.
